# Spring + Hibernate + TestNG + Mocking nothing persist, nothing is readed in test

Tags: spring, hibernate, mocking, testng

Fighting with TestNG, Spring an Hibernate. I'm writing test for Service class, and it's always failure. But without test class works fine. So App is working, but tests don't want to.

Here is my test class

```
@Transactional
public class BorrowerServiceTest {

@Mock
BorrowerDAOImpl borrowerDAO;

@InjectMocks
BorrowerService borrowerService;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void persistTest() {
    Borrower borrower = new Borrower.BorrowerBuilder().firstName("Lars").lastName("Urlich").adress("LA")
            .phoneNumber("900900990").build();
    borrowerService.persist(borrower);
    List<Borrower> borrowerList = borrowerService.getBorrowerByName("Lars Urlich");
    Assert.assertEquals(true, borrower.equals(borrowerList.get(0)));
}

}
```

My BorrowerService:

```
@Service("borrowerService")
@Transactional
public class BorrowerService {

@Autowired
private BorrowerDAO borrowerDAO;

public List<Borrower> getBorrowers() {
    return borrowerDAO.getBorrowers();
}

public List<Borrower> getBorrowerByName(String name) {
    return borrowerDAO.getBorrowerByName(name);
}

public boolean removeBorrower(Borrower borrower) {
    return borrowerDAO.removeBorrower(borrower);
}

public boolean persist(Borrower borrower) {
    return borrowerDAO.persist(borrower);
}
}
```

My BorrowerDAOImpl:

```
@Repository("borrowerDAO")
@Transactional
public class BorrowerDAOImpl extends DAO implements BorrowerDAO {

@Override
public List<Borrower> getBorrowers() {
    List<Borrower> borrowerList = null;
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT B FROM Borrower B");
    borrowerList = query.getResultList();
    return borrowerList;
}

@Override
public List<Borrower> getBorrowerByName(String name) {
    List<Borrower> borrowerList = null;
    String[] values = name.split(" ");
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT B FROM Borrower B WHERE B.firstName LIKE '" + values[0]
            + "' AND B.lastName LIKE '" + values[1] + "'");
    borrowerList = query.getResultList();
    return borrowerList;
}

@Override
public boolean removeBorrower(Borrower borrower) {
    String firstName = borrower.getFirstName();
    String lastName = borrower.getLastName();
    Query query = entityManager
            .createQuery("DELETE Borrower where FIRST_NAME LIKE :FirstName AND LAST_NAME LIKE :LastName");
    query.setParameter("FirstName", firstName);
    query.setParameter("LastName", lastName);
    query.executeUpdate();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean persist(Borrower borrower) {
    entityManager.persist(borrower);
    return true;
}

}
```

and abstract DAO:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public abstract class DAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;  
}
```

Maven returns failure:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:476)
    at com.me.service.test.BorrowerServiceTest.persistTest(BorrowerServiceTest.java:41)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had to fight with this. The problem here is that your test runs in it's own transaction, so nothing will be committed during method's execution. Now here is what I did:

```
public class IntegrationTest extends SomeTestBase
{
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager  platformTransactionManager;

    private TransactionTemplate         transactionTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private BeanToTest beanToTest;

    @Override
    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        super.setup();
        this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(this.platformTransactionManager);
    }

    @Test
    public void fooTest()
    {
        // given

        // when
        boolean result = this.transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public Boolean doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status)
            {
                return IntegrationTest.this.beanToTest.foo();
            }
        });

        // then
    }
}
```

This allows you to have methods execute within a separate transaction. Please note that you might declare some variables as `final`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check [the Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html): it looks your test class should extend `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Commit` annotation on the whole test class or even method to persist changes made in the test. For more information https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#commit